# Back up script causing issues

Tags: centos, backup, out-of-memory

I've got this backup script I'm trying to use and I'm having issues with it.

```
#Setup Variables
DOMAIN=domainexample.com
FILENAME=${DOMAIN}.$(date +%Y%m%d)
DBSERVER=localhost
DATABASE=databasename
USER=mysqluser
PASS=mysqlpass
BACKUPSERVER=user@backupserverinfo:~
BACKUPSERVERPORT=22

# Dump Database for Backup
mysqldump --opt --user=${USER} --password=${PASS} ${DATABASE} > ${FILENAME}.sql

# GZIP the Database File
gzip -f ${FILENAME}.sql

# Make a TEMP DIR and Move the Backup to it for archival
mkdir /var/www/${DOMAIN}/db
cp $FILE.sql.gz /var/www/${DOMAIN}/db

# TAR & GZ domain directory to preserve database, files and images
tar -czvf ~/${FILENAME}.website.tar.gz /var/www/${DOMAIN}

# Remove TEMP DB DIR and Backup
rm -rf /var/www/${DOMAIN}/db

# Transfer backups to backup server
scp -P ${BACKUPSERVERPORT} ${FILENAME}.sql.gz ${FILENAME}.website.tar.gz ${BACKUPSERVER}

# Clear out old backups
rm -rf ~/backups/*

# Move files to temp directory
mv ${FILENAME}.sql.gz ~/backups
mv ${FILENAME}.website.tar.gz ~/backups

# Completed Messages
echo Completed!
```

The problem I run in to is that although I have 3GB of memory and more than 10x the site space available on the hard drive the script causes the server to crash. I start getting errors with httpd stating out of memory. I run this script at 4am local time and the directory size is only 5gb with images and everything. What am I doing wrong?

The actual db file when gzipped is only 4.5mb. The directory though, with images should be around 5gb but a lot of times the file ends up only being 400K. I'm not sure why this is happening.

df -h before I run the command is

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda3        73G   11G   58G  16% /
tmpfs           1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/vda1       477M  194M  258M  43% /boot
```

during gzipping directory

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda3        73G   15G   55G  21% /
tmpfs           1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/vda1       477M  194M  258M  43% /boot
```

free -h is

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2.8G       2.0G       886M       268K        70M       825M
-/+ buffers/cache:       1.1G       1.7G
Swap:         1.0G         0B       1.0G
```

During the gzip

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2.8G       2.7G        74M       276K        42M       1.7G
-/+ buffers/cache:       1.0G       1.8G
Swap:         1.0G       132K       1.0G
```

I never get close to running out of storage and the memory never dips below 74M free.

Comment: Can you add some details to your post, like the size of the sql file, the size of the gzipped file, a `df` and `free` output at the various stages. You don't need to copy the gz around in the fs, just add it to the tar from where it is. You also can use `gzip -9` or even better use `bzip2` or `xz`.

Comment: When it completes it looks like the files are the right size but it only transfers 474K for some reason.